# Set a custom dafault date for a nullable date column on Laravel

Tags: date, laravel-5, migration, default, nullable

I want to set a default date of 1900-01-01 on a nullable date field.

I've tried this

```
$table->date('fecha_nacimiento')->nullable()
    ->default(\Carbon\Carbon::make('1900-01-01')->toDateTimeString());
```

Also

```
$table->date('fecha_nacimiento')->nullable()
    ->default(\Carbon\Carbon::make('1900-01-01'));
```

Also

```
$table->date('fecha_nacimiento')->nullable()->default('1900-01-01');
```

When I save from the browser with the HTML date  input not set, it saves the date field as `null`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default value on the field only applies when no value, not even null, is assigned.

The blank value is most likely from a blank input from a form. Also, if you are using eloquent mass assignment like so,

```
$model->fill($request->all());
```

In this case, your date field is set to null and your insert statement will look like this,

```
INSERT INTO table_name (fecha_nacimiento, ...)
VALUES (null, ...);
```

Comment: I didn't know that. Thanks for the tip.